# How to replace an expression with a variable?

Tags: replacement

Given the following expresion

```
expr = (I Gr0 theta Sqrt[1 - theta^2])/((2 Gr0Mz (-1 + theta^2) (1 - 2 coff1*theta trMz wn + coff1^2 trMz^2 wn^2)) + Sin[a] + Cos[b]) + (Exp[c] + Log[d])/((2 Gr0Mz (-1 + theta^2) (1 - 2 coff1 theta trMz wn + coff1^2 trMz^2 wn^2)) + Exp[c]
       );
```

I want to do the following replacement：

```
(2 Gr0Mz (-1 + theta^2) (1 - 2 coff1 theta trMz wn + coff1^2 trMz^2 wn^2))->Tp
```

How to do?

Comment: `expr /. (2 Gr0Mz (-1 + theta^2) (1 - 2 coff1 theta trMz wn + coff1^2 trMz^2 wn^2)) -> Tp`

Comment: Or `expr /. Gr0Mz -> 
  Tp/ (2 (-1 + theta^2) (1 - 2 coff1 theta trMz wn + 
       coff1^2 trMz^2 wn^2))`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestions by Bill and  Jens in the comments, you can do:

```
Replace[expr, (2 Gr0Mz (-1 + theta^2) (1 - 2 coff1 theta trMz wn + 
       coff1^2 trMz^2 wn^2)) -> Tp, {0, Infinity}]
```

> (E^c + Log[d])/(E^c + Tp) + (I Gr0 theta Sqrt[1 - theta^2])/(
>    Tp + Cos[b] + Sin[a])

or

```
Apart @ Simplify[expr, {(2 Gr0Mz (-1 + theta^2) (1 - 2 coff1 theta trMz wn + 
        coff1^2 trMz^2 wn^2)) == Tp}]
```

> 1 + (-Tp + Log[d])/(E^c + Tp) + (I Gr0 theta Sqrt[1 - theta^2])/(
>        Tp + Cos[b] + Sin[a])

```
Simplify[Equal[%, %%]]
```

> True